# Powershell Script Just Returns with No Log Output

Tags: powershell, docker, kubernetes

**PSA: First time I've used PowerShell, my go-to is Bash or Python, sorry if it looks weird.**

I have created a Powershell script that, if our Windows 2019 Server reboots (powercut for example), it'll check to see if `Get-HnsNetwork | ? Name -eq "l2bridge"` returns.  If there is nothing returned, it then calls the function `Create-Hns` which creates an `External` and `l2bridge` interface which is then used with docker and kubernetes.  Below is the code tha I have so far.

```
function Write-Log {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False, Position=0)]
        [String]$Entry
    )
    "$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff') $Entry" | Out-File -FilePath $LogFilePath -Append
}

Function Create-Hns {
    Write-Log -Entry "Starting to create the HnsNetwork..."
    Try {
        ipmo c:\k\SDN\windows\helper.psm1 -force
        ipmo c:\k\SDN\windows\hns.psm1 -force

        if(!(Get-HnsNetwork | ? Name -eq "External")) {
          New-HNSNetwork `
            -Name "External" `
            -Type NAT `
            -AddressPrefix "192.168.x.x/30" `
            -Gateway "192.168.x.x" `
            -Verbose
        }

        if(!(Get-HnsNetwork | ? Name -eq "l2bridge")) {
          New-HNSNetwork `
            -Name l2bridge `
            -Type L2Bridge `
            -AddressPrefix "192.168.x.x/24" `
            -Gateway "192.168.x.x" `
            -Verbose
        }

        $hnsNetwork = Get-HnsNetwork | ? Name -eq l2bridge
        $hnsEndpoint = New-HnsEndpoint `
                         -NetworkId ($hnsNetwork).Id `
                         -Name "l2bridge" `
                         -IPAddress "192.168.x.x" `
                         -Gateway "0.0.0.0" `
                         -Verbose Attach-HnsHostEndpoint `
                         -EndpointID ($hnsEndpoint).Id `
                         -CompartmentID 1
    } Catch {
        Write-Log -Entry "An error occured"
        Write-Log -Entry $_
        Break
    }
    If ($?) {
        Write-Log -Entry "VERIFY HERE"
        Wrtie-Log -Entry $_
    }   
}

$LogFilePath = "C:\k\CreateHns.log"

$sFetch = (Get-HnsNetwork | ? Name -eq "l2bridge")

If (!$sFetch) {
    Write-Log -Entry "Didn't get any info on l2bridge, we need to create one."
    Create-Hns
Else {
    Write-Log -Entry  "Got information for the l2bridge, nothing needs creating."
    Write-Log -Entry "Nothing to do"
    }
}
```

When I run the script with `./Check-HnsNetwork.ps1` in Powershell, it just returns and doesn't log out to the log file.  According to VS code, it's formatted correctly.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the above code block?  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no error messages?

Comment: There was not, i checked, there were some from the previous night but nothing from this morning.  I have cleaned it up not and its working just fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as scoping is not an issue here, there are some ***errors in the*** ***posted code*** that need to be fixed. If `$sFetch` never evaluates to `$false` or `$null`, the errors do not present themselves at runtime. Consider the following:

- The entry `Wrtie-Log -Entry $_` needs to be changed to `Write-Log -Entry $_`
- `If (!$sFetch) {
  Write-Log -Entry "Didn't get any info on l2bridge, we need to create one."
  Create-Hns` is missing the closing `}`

Comment: Nice, great spot.  Correct that and seems to be working fine.  Just need to check for some services that should be running and we are done.  Thanks for the feedback too.